# Spring boot parsing yaml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

i need to parse configuration from yaml using spring boot in format of Map> and i cant find in manual of spring boot or specific example.Do i need impl. specific parser for this type of parse?

My yaml file:

```
stateMachine :
  allowedActions:
          EMPTY:
           -
             action : 'ADD'
             nextState : 'DRAFT'
           -
             action : 'ADD2'
             nextState : 'ADD2'
          DRAFT:
          -
             action : 'TEST'
             nextState : 'TEST'
```

This my configuration loader:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "stateMachine")
public class StateMachineConfig  {


  private Map<String,List<ActionHolder>> allowedActions = new HashMap<>();




  public Set<String> getInitialStates() {
    return allowedActions.keySet();
  }




  public Map<String, List<ActionHolder>> getStateTransitions() {
    return this.allowedActions;
  }


  public void setStateTransitions(Map<String, List<ActionHolder>> stateTransitions) {
      this.allowedActions = stateTransitions;
  }
}


public class ActionHolder implements IActionHolder {


  private String action;

  private String nextState;

  @Override
  public String getAction() {
    return action;
  }

  @Override
  public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
  }

  public String getNextState() {
    return nextState;
  }

  @Override
  public void setNextState(String nextState) {
    this.nextState = nextState;
  }
}
```

If to use external lib. also is my last option,so my question in general if it possible to parse map from yaml if value is another collection without impl. custom parser?Thnx.

Comment: Spring cannot match your yml map name to your getters and setters. Rename get/setStateTransitions to get/setAllowedActions.

Comment: Thnx, it worked!